# Tabto inserts line break when tabbing into right margin

Tags: margins, marginpar, tabto

I wanted to use `tabto` to insert symbols into the margins of my document. I did this as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabto, calc}
%   \def\marginsymbol{\protect\marginsymbolhelper}
%   \def\marginsymbolhelper{\tabto*{-1ex}\makebox[0cm]{$\bullet$}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}
%   The following works, too:
    \newcommand{\marginsymbol}{\tabto*{-3.5ex}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay 
        ]%
        \node[circle, fill=pink] at (0, 0) {\textcolor{white!90!pink}{\LARGE\textbf{i}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}%
    \newcommand{\marginsig}{\tabto*{\textwidth + 3.5ex}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay 
        ]%
        \node[circle, fill=pink] at (0, 0) {\textcolor{white!90!pink}{\LARGE\textbf{i}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}       
        }%
        \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}
        }%


\begin{document}
\section{Eins}
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum\marginsymbol  
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser\marginsig Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum

\end{document}
```

The symbol in the right margin (\marginsig) causes the text to continue at the right position, but in the next line. This problem is independent of using a tikzpicture environment, or tikz at all.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure, that you are not searching for `\marginpar` or `\marginline` maybe together with `\reversemarginpar`?

Comment: ```\marginpar```seems not to place the content in the margin i want it to (tried with ```\reversemarginpar``` and the ```mparhack``` package), but ```marginnote``` from the resp. package works fine! I thought my approach was more flexible, but this seems to work fine, too.

Comment: `\marginpar` does also work. See the second example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to print material into the margins. In your case it seems, you want to print into the left and the right margin. Because you are already using a KOMA-Script class, here is a suggestion using the KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-notecolumn`, that provides the usage of several note columns:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% 11pt is the default and therefore not needed
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,scrlayer-notecolumn}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\marginsymbol}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, fill=pink] at (0, 0) {\textcolor{white!90!pink}{\LARGE\textbf{i}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%
\DeclareNewNoteColumn[reversemarginpar]{reversemarginpar}
\NewDocumentCommand{\marginsign}{s}
{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\makenote[reversemarginpar]{\raggedleft\marginsymbol}}%
    {\makenote{\marginsymbol}}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{Eins}
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum\marginsign*
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser\marginsign{} Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

After two LaTeX runs you'd get:

[image: left and right margin mark with scrlayer-scrpage]

But to be kind: You don't need an extra package, you can simply use `\marginpar` with a trick to reach the left margin:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% 11pt is the default and therefore not needed
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,scrlayer-notecolumn}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\marginsymbol}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, fill=pink] at (0, 0) {\textcolor{white!90!pink}{\LARGE\textbf{i}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%
%\DeclareNewNoteColumn[reversemarginpar]{reversemarginpar}
\NewDocumentCommand{\marginsign}{s}
{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\marginpar{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-\dimexpr\textwidth+2\marginparsep}\raisebox{-\ht\strutbox}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\marginsymbol}}}}}%
    {\marginpar{\raisebox{-\ht\strutbox}{\marginsymbol}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{Eins}
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum\marginsign*
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser\marginsign{} Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum Dieser Text ist nicht Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: left and right margin mark with \marginpar]